# How to configure new date () in angular or javascript to have the correct format of the dd / MM / YYYY

Tags: javascript, angular, date, calendar, momentjs

When I send this date format "dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm" to new date('05/07/2019 10:00')
he sends me back Tue May 07 2019 10:00:00 GMT + 0200 .I wanted that date Fri Jul 05 2019 GMT + 0200.I use a date format french

Comment: Every possible date parsing and formatting question has already been asked and answered here. Please [**search**](/help/searching) before posting.

Comment: Start with [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) ECMAScript's parser is quirky and seriously in need modernising, avoid it where possible (which is always). ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Please Follow below steps:

step1:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

step2:

```
this.date.date = new Date()
```

step3:

```
let ds = this.date.date.toString();
let date = moment(new Date(ds.substr(0, 16)));
```

step4:

```
let finalOutPut = date.format("dd/MM/YYYY")
```

Thanks